# How to sort where an object is added to based on it's attribute

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

I am wondering if someone can elucidate a method that adds objects with the same attribute value to seperate lists.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Don't forget to mark answer as accepted, if it solved your question, if it didn't pls clarify your Question.

Comment: @RandRandom Thanks for the reminder - will update tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using a `Dictionary<int, List<Candidate>>` instead of multiple lists.

Your `CandidateList` could look like this:

```
public class CandidateList
{
    private Dictionary<int, List<Candidate>> _candidatesByFrameNumber;

    public CandidateList()
    {
        _candidatesByFrameNumber = new Dictionary<int, List<Candidate>>();
    }

    public void Add(Candidate candidate)
    {
        if (!_candidatesByFrameNumber.TryGetValue(candidate.FrameNumber, out var lst))
        {
            lst = new List<Candidate>();
            _candidatesByFrameNumber.Add(candidate.FrameNumber, lst);
        }

        lst.Add(candidate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need multiple lists at all. you are complicating the problem. 
all that you need is just one simple list to store your `Candidates` and get query from the list by `frameNumber` or other fields.

```cs
public class CandidateList
{
    public List<Candidate> _CandidatesList;

    public CandidateList()
    {
        _CandidatesList = new List<Candidate>();
    }

    // actually you need this method anymore
    // you can use _CandidatesList.Add() instead.
    public void Add(Candidate candidate)
    {
        _CandidatesList.Add(candidate);
    }


    public IEnumerable<Candidate> GetCandidateByFrameNumber(int frameNumber)
    {
        // this is how you can query the data depending your needs and get seprated results.
        return _CandidatesList.Where(q => q.FrameNumber == frameNumber );
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CandidateList
{

 private List<Dictionary<Int, Candidate>> candidatList;

 public CandidateList()
 {
    candidatList= new List<Dictionary<int, Candidate>>();
 }

 public void Add(Candidate candidate)
 {

    Var element = New <Dictionary<candidate.FrameNumber, Candidate>();
    candidatList.Add(element);
 }

 public List<Candidate> GetList(int frameNum)
 {
    List<Candidate> lst = New List<Candidate>()
    foreach (int key in CandidateList.Keys)
    {
        if (key == frameNum)
        {
          lst.Add(CandidateList[key])
        }
    }
    return lst; 
 }
}
```